# Adding columns and insert info from a second dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, join

hello everyone I have two dataframes and I'd like to join information from one df to another one in a specific way. I'm gonna explain better. Here is my first df where i'd like to add 6 columns (general col named col1, col2 and so on..):

```
           res1 res4 aa1234 
1 AAAAAA    1    4   IVGG       
2 AAAAAA    8   11   RPRQ        
3 AAAAAA   10   13   RQFP        
4 AAAAAA   12   15   FPFL  
5 AAAAAA   20   23   NQGR      
6 AAAAAA   32   35   HARF
```

here is the 2nd df:

```
   res1     dist
    1     3.711846
    1     3.698985
    2     4.180874
    2     3.112819
    3     3.559737
    3     3.722107
    4     3.842375
    4     3.914970
    5     3.361647
    5     2.982788
    6     3.245118
    6     3.224230
    7     3.538315
    7     3.602273
    8     3.185184
    8     2.771583
    9     4.276871
    9     3.157737
    10    3.933783
    10    2.956738
```

Considering "res1" I'd like to add to the 1st df in my new 6 columns the first 6th values contained in "dist" of second df corresponding to res1 = 1.
After, in the 1st df I have res1 = 8, so I'd like to add in the new 6 columns the 6 values from res1 = 8 contained in "dist" of 2nd df.

I'd like to obtain something like this

```
res1 res4   aa1234  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
      1    4   IVGG    3.71 3.79 4.18 3.11 3.55 3.72
      8   11   RPRQ    3.18 2.77 4.27 3.15 3.93 2.95
     10   13   RQFP    
     12   15   FPFL        
     20   23   NQGR   
     32   35   HARF
```

Please consider that I have to do it on a large dataset and for 1000 and more files... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a sequence from `res1` to `res4` and then join the data with `pdb`.

```
library(tidyverse)

turn %>%
  mutate(res = map2(res1, res4, seq)) %>%
  unnest(res) %>%
  left_join(pdb, by = c('res' = 'res1')) %>%
  group_by(res1 = as.character(res1)) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('col', row_number())) %>%
  select(-res4, -res, -eleno) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = dist)
```

Comment: I reported only columns I was interested, I have also columns with character. Infact I got this error:  Can't join on `x$res1` x `y$res1` because of incompatible types.
i `x$res1` is of type <integer>>.
i `y$res1` is of type <character>>.

Comment: Then select only those columns that you are interested in same as your example shown so you'll not get the error. `df2 <- df2 %>% select(res1, res4)` and `df1 <- df1 %>% select(res1, dist)`.

Comment: I can't because i need that columns with char, my mistake was on posting the question, sorry. After res1 and res4, I have other colums of type char that I can't remove, but I have to add my 6 col as posted in the question

Comment: @Nancy Can you try the updated answer? I turned `res1` of `df2` to character so the types match.

Comment: @Nancy Could you add your data or sample of data using `dput` so that I can check the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new on programming and using this website, what do you need?

Comment: Add `dput(pdb)` and `dput(turn)` to your post. If the data is too big you can add only first 10 rows or so using head i.e `dput(head(pdb, 10))`

Comment: Hmmm...I don't exactly get the complete picture but can you try if the updated answer takes closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Nancy I think I had misunderstood your question earlier. The updated answer should give you 6 columns.

Comment: it's really close to what I need but now I got 8 columns and not 6, but the values putted are corrected. And I lost column "res4" in df "Turn"

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df2 %>%
    mutate(col = str_c("col", rowid(res1))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = dist) %>%
    right_join(df1, by = 'res1')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#   res1  col1  col2  res4
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1  3.71  3.70     4
#2     8  3.19  2.77    11
#3    10  3.93  2.96    13
#4    12 NA    NA       15
#5    20 NA    NA       23
#6    32 NA    NA       35
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(res1 = c(1L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 20L, 32L), res4 = c(4L, 
11L, 13L, 15L, 23L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2 <- structure(list(res1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), dist = c(3.711846, 
3.698985, 4.180874, 3.112819, 3.559737, 3.722107, 3.842375, 3.91497, 
3.361647, 2.982788, 3.245118, 3.22423, 3.538315, 3.602273, 3.185184, 
2.771583, 4.276871, 3.157737, 3.933783, 2.956738)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: I got the same error of the previous answer, pls read comments

Comment: @Nancy thanks.  Can you update your post with the `dput` of the examples showed so that I can understand the structure of your data while testing

Comment: @Nancy I updated the post with the output I got and the data used